# How to reference img in javascript in a vue component when it is loaded with javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

> **File Structure** (Webpack)

```
src
-assets
--img
---myimage.png
-vue
--page
---parent.vue
---component
----child.vue
```

> **parent.vue** : Here I tried `src` relative to this component and relative to the child component where the image will be actually loaded.

```
/** This data is passed to the child component in a loop */
data(){
  return{
    items: [
      { id: 1, src: '../../../assets/img/myImage.png'},
      more items...
    ]
  }
}
```

> **child.vue** : I get the following error in the console: **Error in mounted hook: "Error: Cannot find module '../../../assets/img/myImage.png'"**

```
props: {
  item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
  }
},
mounted() {
  let element = this.$refs['myelement'];
  let img = new Image();

  img.onload = function(){
      element.insertBefore(this, element.firstChild);
  }
  img.src = require(this.item.src);
},
```

I have tried every combination possible for the src, I even copied the image file in the component directory and referenced it like `myImage.png` and `./myImage.png`, but the same error appears.
What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever images are placed inside src/assets its moved into static/img/imagename when webpack builds

Try to access those images from browser directly using urls like localhost:8080/static/img/imagename.png

If that is accessible, then rewrite the array with only image file name and prepend with /static/img

Comment: No, it didn't work. This did work : `http://localhost:8080/src/assets/img/myImage.png`

Comment: It won' work in that way. After bundling in webpack all the assets are moved to static folder. You can access from there by http://localhost/static/img/myImage.png

Comment: That is the problem, I can't bundle it, I get the error:  Error in mounted hook: "Error: Cannot find module '../../../assets/img/myImage.png'"